# Email when IIS stops or restarts?

Tags: iis, azure

Is there an option to receive an email alert when IIS stops and restarts?

I should get an email alert when the IIS stops and also an email alert when it starts.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such monitoring services in Azure. In fact I doubt there is such service in any cloud vendor.

What is there however is pretty well written manual on [how to configure monitoring and alerts for Azure Web Sites here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-monitor/).

There is also monitoring and alerting for Cloud Services, Virtual Machines, SQL Database. [All described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn306639.aspx).

What you can monitor - is availability of your Web Site / Cloud Service / VM. Whether IIS is stopping or starting however is not subject of that monitoring.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will go through it. Is there any way through which we can get alerts if an application or IIS stops and starts? Please advise.

Comment: StackOverflow is not free advisory board! If you have concrete programming question, feel free to ask. If you are seeking advice, go to some consulting company!